# Manually create Apple hidden e-Mail addresses @privaterelay.appleid.com

Tags: icloud, apple-id, development, privacy

I would love to create a handfull of private/disposable e-Mail adresses with my Apple ID - i can manage and see right here: https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage

If i sign in for example at pocket.com they have the private format kdf9s4js6ekw@privaterelay.appleid.com

Who has an idea or system to create them manually, may be with their own description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use your privaterelay.appleid.com as disposable adresses is not possible at the moment, because it accepts only the developer id who created it as a sender.

> It's important to understand that the email address given to the
>   developer (you), in this case:  xxxxxprm23@privaterelay.appleid.com
>
> may only be used from the email domains (with SPF records) or full
>   email addresses registered in the Developer Portal.  It is not
>   currently possible for you as a developer to hand that email address
>   to a third-party and expect to be able to route through the
>   privaterelay.appleid.com MTAs.  Unfortunately, it's also not possible
>   to register any third-party domain such as mandrillapp.com as one of
>   your email source domains.
>
> At this time, mail API services that send email from their own MTAs on
>   behalf of their developer customers do not work through
>   privaterelay.appleid.com.  The only available workaround currently is
>   to setup your own MTA and emit mail from one of your registered
>   domains.
>
> We are aware of this issue and are working on a solution that would
>   allow developers to use these mail API services.
>
> Stay tuned...

Reference https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/121256